# how to filter dictionary values if its key exists in a string[] using linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
string[] strLst = { "One", "Three" };
        Dictionary<string, Customer> dicDocTypes = new Dictionary<string, Customer>();
        dicDocTypes.Add("One", new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Rabi" });
        dicDocTypes.Add("Two", new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Shuvankar" });
        dicDocTypes.Add("Three", new Customer { Id = 3, Name = "Krishna" });
        dicDocTypes.Add("Four", new Customer { Id = 4, Name = "Suresh" });

        var rootNodes = from node in dicDocTypes
                        where node.Key.Contains(**strLst**)
                        select new KeyValuePair<string, Customer>(node.Key, node.Value);
```

Question: how to filter dictionary items if the keys matches with a string[]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to ask the key if it belongs to an array, you can ask the array if it contains the key:

```
var rootNodes = from node in dicDocTypes
                where strLst.Contains(node.Key)
                select new KeyValuePair<string, Customer>(node.Key, node.Value);
```

If you have a lot of items, it will be faster to use a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of an array (O(1) lookups instead of O(n) lookups):

```
var strLst = new HashSet<string> { "One", "Three" };
```

Also, you can simplify the select to this:

```
var rootNodes = dicDocTypes.Where(n => strLst.Contains(n.Key));
```

Additionally, there's a cleaner way to initialize dictionaries:

```
var dicDocTypes = new Dictionary<string, Customer> {
    { "One", new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "Rabi" } },
    { "Two", new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Shuvankar" } },
    { "Three", new Customer { Id = 3, Name = "Krishna" } },
    { "Four", new Customer { Id = 4, Name = "Suresh" } }
};
```

Comment: I was looking exactly for something like the 3rd code snippet, helps a lot thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Cameron has said, you're just asking the question the wrong way round. However, you can *also* make your code simpler - the "node" in a dictionary is already a `KeyValuePair`, so all you need is:

```
var rootNodes = dicDocTypes.Where(pair => strLst.Contains(pair.Key));
```

If you need a new dictionary at the end, you can use the `ToDictionary` method:

```
var rootNodes = dicDocTypes.Where(pair => strLst.Contains(pair.Key))
                           .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

If your list of strings to filter by becomes longer, you might want to consider making it a `HashSet<string>` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootNodes = dicDocTypes.Join(strList, kvp => kvp.Key, s => s, (kvp, str) => kvp);
```